# Installing awscli without internet

Tags: setuptools, aws-cli

I am trying to install awscli on a RHEL machine.
Python 2.7.5 is installed, the machine does not have internet access.

I have installed setuptools 38.5.2 and setuptools_scm 1.15.7 from sources successfully.

Here is the command I have tried to run when installing:

```
sudo /usr/bin/python2.7 awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws sudo awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
```

Both are exiting with the following issue:

```
Running cmd: /usr/bin/python virtualenv.py --no-download --python /usr/bin/python /usr/local/aws
Running cmd: /usr/local/aws/bin/pip install --no-index --find-links file:///home/talendmaster/QlikSensePOC/awscli-bundle/packages awscli-1.14.54.tar.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "awscli-bundle/install", line 143, in <module>
    main()
  File "awscli-bundle/install", line 132, in main
    pip_install_packages(opts.install_dir)
  File "awscli-bundle/install", line 100, in pip_install_packages
    pip_script, PACKAGES_DIR, cli_tarball))
  File "awscli-bundle/install", line 45, in run
    p.returncode, cmd, stdout + stderr))
__main__.BadRCError: Bad rc (1) for cmd '/usr/local/aws/bin/pip install --no-index --find-links file:///home/talendmaster/QlikSensePOC/awscli-bundle/packages awscli-1.14.54.tar.gz': Processing ./awscli-1.14.54.tar.gz
Collecting botocore==1.9.7 (from awscli==1.14.54)
Collecting colorama<=0.3.7,>=0.2.5 (from awscli==1.14.54)
Collecting docutils>=0.10 (from awscli==1.14.54)
Collecting rsa<=3.5.0,>=3.1.2 (from awscli==1.14.54)
Collecting s3transfer<0.2.0,>=0.1.12 (from awscli==1.14.54)
Collecting PyYAML<=3.12,>=3.10 (from awscli==1.14.54)
Collecting jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 (from botocore==1.9.7->awscli==1.14.54)
Collecting python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 (from botocore==1.9.7->awscli==1.14.54)
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/setuptools_scm/: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable -- Some packages may not be found!
    Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/setuptools-scm/: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable -- Some packages may not be found!
    Couldn't find index page for 'setuptools_scm' (maybe misspelled?)
    Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable -- Some packages may not be found!
    No local packages or working download links found for setuptools_scm
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-kh_Hg9/python-dateutil/setup.py", line 67, in <module>
        "test": Unsupported
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 112, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 315, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
      File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 361, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 850, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
      File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1122, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1134, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 429, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 659, in easy_install
        raise DistutilsError(msg)
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('setuptools_scm')

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-kh_Hg9/python-dateutil/
```

It seems to be related to setuptools_scm but reinstallation did not change anything. The internet access shouldn't be a problem since I have successfully installed a local version of the package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just finished installing AWS CLI tools on an old RHEL 5.10 machine, this works for me as on date.

```
$ curl -LO https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip
$ unzip awscli-bundle.zip
$ ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
Running cmd: /root/aws/bin/python virtualenv.py --no-download --python /root/aws/bin/python /usr/local/aws
Running cmd: /usr/local/aws/bin/pip install --no-index --find-links file:///root/awscli-bundle/packages/setup setuptools_scm-1.15.7.tar.gz
Running cmd: /usr/local/aws/bin/pip install --no-index --find-links file:///root/awscli-bundle/packages awscli-1.15.68.tar.gz
You can now run: /usr/local/bin/aws --version
$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.15.68 Python/2.6.8 Linux/2.6.18-363.el5 botocore/1.10.67
```

References:

- https://medium.com/@vikas027/aws-cli-tools-in-rhel-centos-5-cd4b9beeb096 (my post)
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-bundle.html#install-bundle-other